# ASP.NET new project with Visual C# has two "ASP.NET Web Application" options

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

[image]

Just want to know whats the difference(if any) is between option 1 and 7.

EDIT:

The details on the right side are same for both the options.

Comment: Well, what does the details on the right say for each project type?

Comment: Details are the same. I forgot to add that part in my question. ty

Comment: If you create an empty project with each template, then diff them, what are the differences?

Comment: I just have one option in my VS.

Comment: also just have one. They're probably the same maybe you managed to find a bug of some sort within the IDE

Comment: @MarkCooper Looks the same.

Comment: @MohammedSohailEbrahim I guess. Just wanted to be sure since i am new to .net

Comment: its cool if you have any issues just holla at me. I'm on many networks